# how to insert php array into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I have an php array that im trying to insert into a mysql table without success, The table structure has two fields, id (int auto increment primary key), and name (varchar), the code is :

```
<?php


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($connect->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

//get values for array
$domains_test = $client->sites_web_domain_get($session_id, array('domain' => 
'%'));




foreach($domains_test as $domains) { 

 $arr = explode('.', $domains['domain']);
 unset($arr[0]);
$arry = implode('.', $arr);


$testsql = "INSERT INTO table1 (id, name) VALUES ('','".$arry."')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $testsql)) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $testsql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);

}

?>
```

The query inserts the first value into the table, but I get the following error :

```
> New record created successfully
Error: INSERT INTO table1 (id, name) VALUES ('','john')
Error: INSERT INTO popular_domains2 (id, name) VALUES ('','fred')
Error: INSERT INTO popular_domains2 (id, name) VALUES ('','james')
```

The records I am inserting may contain duplicate values. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try not passing the id value. $testsql = "INSERT INTO table1 ( name) VALUES ('".$arry."')";

Comment: do not pass an empty string for the id column, you may either pass NULL or your omit the column altogether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line

```
$testsql = "INSERT INTO table1 (id, name) VALUES ('','".$arry."')";
```

to

```
$testsql = "INSERT INTO table1 (name) VALUES ('".$arry."')";
```

Comment: Hi Mizanur, thanks for your response!, that was the first thing I tried but I still get the same error.

Comment: Empty the table first then run the query again. Let me know this.

Comment: Hi  Mizanur, The result is still the same, the first element of the array is inserted into the table, then I get errors for the rest. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Did you change the query? May I see your table structure also the errors.

Comment: Hi, I have changed the query to

Comment: please move the line mysqli_close($conn); after foreach end and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As per your post id is auto increment and primary key 
So why you use  INSERT INTO table1 (id, name) VALUES ('','john') .this is wrong because I'd field auto increment automatically not manual. So just removed the query and paste it INSERT INTO table1 ( name) VALUES (''john')